# Setting value as object in JSON-LD expansion

Tags: json, data-conversion, expansion, json-ld, linked-data

I try to convert `JSON` to `JSON-LD` and was wondering if I could use `JSON-LD` expansion algorithm for creating my converter. Then I could just specify my schema as a context and run the expansion algorithm for doing the conversion. Problem is that I cannot figure out how to define new value objects in context so that the expansion algorithm would work.

Let's say I have this:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-01-08T11:01:38Z"
}
```

and I want to get this:

```
{
  "prefix:time": {"prefix:start": "2016-01-08T11:01:38Z"}
}
```

I have tried it using the JSON-LD playground with something like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "timestamp": {
      "@id": "prefix:time",
      "@value": {"prefix:start": "@value"}
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2016-01-08T11:01:38Z"
}
```

But the expanded result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "prefix:time": [
      {
        "@value": "2016-01-08T11:01:38Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way to use the `JSON-LD` expansion (or other) algorithm to replace the value with a new `JSON` object?

Comment: It seems that this is not possible with JSON-LD algorithms. I moved forward to use JSON to JSON transformation library - Jolt for the job. It also has some limitations, but can cover some simple cases. However, keep in mind that Jolt cannot be used for changing the values in the JSON document, only moving them into different places.

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt

Comment: "It also has some limitations, but can cover some simple cases. However, keep in mind that Jolt cannot be used for changing the values in the JSON document, only moving them into different places."        Yep, that was the idea.   "changing the values" is business logic, and that can be implemented after Jolt or as a custom Jolt transform.

Answer (score 1):

This Jolt transform does the transform you described.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "timestamp": "prefix:time.prefix:start"
    }
  }
]
```

You can try it out at http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/